# Presentation of Case Sensitive fields in standard layouts

Tags: visualforce

Say I have a field that contains data that is sensitive to errors like telling the difference between an I and l. That's `I` and `l`, which may appear identical depending on the font your browser is using. 0 and O (`0` and `O`) is another common example of characters than can be difficult to distinguish.

If I show this field on a standard page layout users won't be able to easily pick the differences between the characters. The default font-family for a dataCol `td` is Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif.

**How can I change the font-family for this field in a standard layout?**

If I was using this field in a Visualforce page in an apex:outputText I could use the style attribute to change the font-family.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/overriding-salesforce-css-with-custom-css

Comment: @mast0r It's an option, but I'd rather not deal with the repercussions of changing the font family on all dataCols. My CSS selector Foo isn't strong enough to target just the one field in question.

Comment: Are you happy to create a VF page and drop it into a section on the native layout? You can make the VF page small, the size of the field you want to show and enable the label to the left of it. With this approach it looks like part of the standard layout, but is actually rendered via VF as per your needs.

Comment: @AndrewFawcett An inline VF page with an apex:outputText is certainly a viable solution.

Comment: @Daniel: You could add javascript / jquery in the side bar component and could override the style from there. This would also be helpful in extending to other fields as well.

Comment: On the idea exchange: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp1pAAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an inline VF page for your standard layout which renders the field as per your font requirements. You can make this as small as a standard field on the layout and enable the Label for the VF page to be displayed, thus giving the VF page label the field label, the appearance you get is much the same as the standard layout displaying the field.

Comment: This solution will display the field properly, but doesn't allow for editing the field on the page layout edit page.

Comment: Agreed, the question does tend to lean towards it being a visual clue requirement, though its not 100% stated edit is not a requirement i agree. If so, a custom button on the page to lead to a VF page purpose built for editing and previewing as they edited would be needed.